# Proof that difference of Martingale Sequence is a Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

$\left\{ Z_{n},n\geq1\right\} $ is a martingale, which means that $\forall n$,
it satisfies the below two conditions,

1) This is the uniformly bounded condition.
$$
E\left[\left|Z_{n}\right|\right]<\infty
$$

2) Standard martingalge condition.
$$
E\left[\left.Z_{n+1}\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right]=Z_{n}
$$

## Question:

How do we prove that $\left\{ Z_{m+k}-Z_{m},m\geq1,k=1,\ldots,n\right\} $ is a martingale?

## Context:

This is an omitted step in the proof of the Martingale Convergence Theorem from Stochastic Processes, Second Edition, Sheldon Ross, Theorem 6.4.6, Page 315.

## Steps Tried:

$$
\text{Let, }Y_{k}=Z_{m+k}-Z_{m}
$$
$$
E\left[\left.Y_{k+1}\right|Y_{k}\ldots Y_{1}\right]=E\left[\left.Z_{m+k+1}-Z_{m}\right|Z_{m+k}-Z_{m},\ldots,Z_{m+1}-Z_{m}\right]
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you need one more condition on measurability in the definition of martingale.

Comment: @SiXUlm Please note, I am using the definition from Stochastic Processes, Second Edition, Sheldon Ross. I am not aware of the measurability condition. Since this book is mostly a non-measure theoretic approach.  Also, I have added the steps tried above. Please feel free to suggest anything I need to include with full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll use the tower property of conditional expectation, and first condition on a larger set of random variables. First since $Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots, Z_{m+1}-Z_m,Z_m$ and $Z_{m+k},\dots,Z_m$ determine the same events, we have

$$E [Z_{m+k+1} | Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m,Z_m]=E[Z_{m+k+1} |Z_{m+k},\dots,Z_m]=Z_{m+k}=(*)$$

By the tower property, to get the conditional expectation of $Z_{m+K+1}$ WRT to the smaller set of variables $Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m$, we take the conditional expectation of $(*)$ with respect to the latter set (tower property):

$$E[Z_{m+k+1} | Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m]=E [ Z_{m+k} |Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m],$$

But this gives

$$E[Z_{m+k+1} - Z_m | Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m ] = E [ Z_{m+k}-Z_m  |Z_{m+k}-Z_m,\dots,Z_{m+1}-Z_m ] = Z_{m+k}-Z_m,$$

which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Much appreciative of this clear and complete answer. As I read it, the key was adding $Z_m$ into the conditional expectation and then conditioning on a smaller set without it.